# How to resolve placeholder value in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Kindly help with accessing values from yaml file in Sprint Boot. I am getting error  as below. I am able to access value of filepath1 variable in AppConfig class but not sure why its giving the error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'filepath1' in value "${filepath1}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:178)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:239)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210)
```

My main class is as follows

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Starting ");
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(DemoApplication.class);

        Employee employee = applicationContext.getBean(Employee.class);
        System.out.println("Exiting ");
    }

}
```

Config class is as follows

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.vish.springbootdemo.demo")
public class AppConfig
{

    @Value("${filepath1}")
    private String file1;

    @Bean
    public Employee employee()
    {
        System.out.println("file1 is " + file1);
        return  new Employee();
    }
}
```

Here is the application.yml

```
filepath1: "vish"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in the `main` method, you are creating your own application context:

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext =
        new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(DemoApplication.class);
```

This will be completely separate from the application context that Spring Boot creates for you, and won't have the configuration properties from `application.yml` in it.

Instead of doing this, use the application context that Spring Boot provides. Even better: Don't explicitly lookup a bean in the application context, but let Spring Boot autowire the bean for you.

Something like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private Employee employee;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Employee: " + employee);
    }
}
```

AppConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Value("${filepath1}")
    private String file1;

    @Bean
    public Employee employee() {
        System.out.println("file1 is " + file1);
        return new Employee();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your input , its working as expected  . One question here are we using CommandLineRunner so as to avoid making object static or is there any other reason . Can you please explain

Comment: Yes, that has to do with `static`. For autowiring, Spring needs an object instance, so it doesn't work from static methods. Spring creates an instance of class `DemoApplication` as a bean in the Spring context, in which it can autowire the `Employee` object. Spring Boot automatically calls the `run` method of beans that implement interface `CommandLineRunner`.

Answer (score 0):

Start your spring boot application like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
}
```

Resources folder should contain application.yml.

```
filepath1: vish
```

Inject your bean with @Autowired

```
@Component
class AnotherComponent {
  @Autowired Employee employee;
}
```